# SQL Server 2008 sp_send_dbmail

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm using SQL Server's

```
sp_send_dbmail
```

to distribute mail.  Everything is working fine; BUT I tried to test a `bad email address` and it always reports success; and nothing is in the failed sent items table.

Will this procedure report IF the email isn't sent?  Or is `success` just getting the mail to the exchange server?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take a look at the `sysmail_allitems` table (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175056.aspx).  What is the `sent_status` for that test email to the bad email address?

Comment: Both my valid and invalid test email addresses report a sent_status of 1.  I think sql server knows it reached (or was sent to) the mail server, but doesn't know if it got sent.

Comment: I just tested in sql 2008 to a bad address and the sent_status shows up as failed for me

Comment: bad To: email address? hmmm, what mail server are you using?  I'm using Exchange with a "service account" and Anonymous authentication.

Comment: Would you mind sharing your config settings?

Comment: Generic mail profile that works with our various sp's and alert jobs, several smtp accounts, all going to our smtp server on port 587, anonymous. Works with port 25 too

Comment: sp_send_dbmail is called from where?  Another stored proc, client code?

Comment: for this testing I am just calling it with t-sql and a query window. I even created a test agent job that calls sp_send_dbmail and uses a bad email address and the job succeeds but the sent_status is failed in sysmail_allitems. Not sure where else to look at this point. Sorry

Answer (score 4):

The procedure will not report if the email is not received. It will be upon you and your support team to troubleshoot why the email was not received. SQL Server just cares about being able to execute the call. Thomas Stringer pointed out sysmail_allitems in a comment and that will show failed status:

```
USE msdb;
select recipients, sent_status
FROM sysmail_allitems
GO
```

If it actually failed the sent_status field will show failed

Edit: Found some more stuff. sp_send_dbmail does not provide a function for "feedback" on the success or failure of the email. You can check the status using the sysmail_xxx tables and in the database mail log. The best I have been able to do on an AD exchange server relaying through anonymous SMTP is a failed status in sysmail_allitems and an error msg in the Database mail log stating unknown user

Links [Jack Corbett](http://wiseman-wiseguy.blogspot.com/2009/09/what-happened-to-that-email.html)

Comment: Thank you.  Unfortunately, my sysmail_allitems never show failure...if I could get that feedback, it would be better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can't verify if the message has been delivered, or even if the address is correct. The procedure doesn't "send" a message, it just places it in Database Mail Queue. Notice that the result of sp is actually "Mail queued.", not "Mail sent" :).

The result/status of sending queued messages can be viewed here, in `[description]` column:

```
SELECT top 100 * FROM msdb..sysmail_log
```

You'd probably have to join the log to mail items:

```
SELECT top 100 * FROM msdb..sysmail_mailitems
```